# Xcode simulator not calling traitCollectionDidChange

Tags: swift3, ios-simulator, xcode8, screen-rotation, uitraitcollection

I am overriding `traitCollectionDidChange(_)` to update my compact and regular constraints. When I test this on a device by rotating the constraints get updated correctly. When I however try to test the same code in the simulator nothing happens. I interjected print statements and I can see that on simulator rotation nothing happens. Is this a bug, or do I need to do something special for the simulator?

Thanks in advance. I am using Xcode 8.2.1 btw.

This is my code:

```
    private var compactConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var regularConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var sharedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    ...
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if (!sharedConstraints[0].isActive) {
            // activating shared constraints
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(sharedConstraints)
        }


        if (self.traitCollection.containsTraits(in: UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact))) {

            print("going to activate: compact")
            if regularConstraints.count > 0 && regularConstraints[0].isActive {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(regularConstraints)
            }
            // activating compact constraints
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(compactConstraints)
        } else {
            print("going to activate: regular")
            if compactConstraints.count > 0 && compactConstraints[0].isActive {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(compactConstraints)
            }
            // activating regular constraints
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
        }

    }
```

The console output is as follows:

```
[launch app]
`going to activate: compact`
[rotate the simulator with ⌘ arrow key]
`going to activate: compact`
```

Small update based on `hoshy`'s question: 
I am using the simulator with iPhone devices. Specifically iPhone SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`horizontalSizeClass` is `Compact` for both orientations. `verticalSizeClass` is `regular` for `portrait` and `Compact` for `landscape` for iPhone SE. You can change this line

```
if (traitCollection.containsTraits(in: UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .compact))) {
```

or simply

```
if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
```

---

You can also use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` if you are looking for animation to run alongside the size change animation.

[Building an Adaptive Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BuildinganAdaptiveInterface.html) from apple developer

> If your Auto Layout constraints are insufficient to achieve the look
>   you want, you can use the
>   `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method to make
>   changes to your layout. You can also use that method to create
>   additional animations to run alongside the size-change animations. For
>   example, during an interface rotation, you might use the transition
>   coordinator’s targetTransform property to to create a counter-rotation
>   matrix for parts of your interface.

Comment: Thanks - so obvious. :-) I have adapted the if-else statement to check both vertical and horizontalSizeClasses. That way I can deal better with iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your actual test device is an iPhone and your simulator is an iPad? The traitCollectionDidChange method will not be called on the latter, since both orientations would be 'regular'.

Comment: I selected iPhone SE as simulator device.